# How to store a name of a function in an array and call it when needed?

Tags: php, arrays, function

If I have a set of function names in an array ,how can I call a function automatically according to a user response,

array is like this ,

```
$functions=array("setName($param)" ,"getName()");
```

Functions are defined elsewhere in the code , I need a solution without using anonymous functions, is this possible? (Sorry for my bad English )

Comment: Take a look at `call_user_func()`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php

Comment: And if you say "set of function names", then you should actually _have_ function names, not something close to function names like `setName($param)` which certainly is _not_ simply a function name.